# Is it possible to make a grid control act as a container control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am using Silverlight and eventually Silverlight for the Phone.

What I am trying to do is create a bordered container which contains children controls.  The children controls should not be visible when outside the bounds of the grid control.

Is this possible?  I know I can create a clip from path, but is this the only way.

I did use a scroll container, which seemed to work.... somewhat.

This is the xaml.  What I am expecting is the second button not be visible when the app is runing.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="197" Width="241" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment">
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="25,42,101,81"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="76" Margin="25,0,63,-83" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking -- normally, child elements would not be visible outside a Grid element unless you were using something like a TranslateTransform.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is the contained grids bounds seems to not do anything except act as reference points.  The contained grid seems to be the same size as the root (virtually)

Comment: I still do not understand your question, but to answer your last comment, a Grid always takes the size of its container, so the contained Grid would be exactly the same size as the LayoutRoot Grid.

Comment: I added the xaml above.  The first button is in the expected visible portion of the grid.  The second button is outside the grid, but it is still visible in the layout root.  I just want to know how to make the second contained grid act like a window.

Comment: OK, if you want the second button not to display, use Ross' answer below because your Margin acts like a TranslateTransform and pushes the button outside the Grid.  Not sure why you would do this; to make a Button hide, it's better to just set its Visibility to Collapsed.

Comment: I am trying to animate the grid growing bringing the button into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around but would love to use another solution.  I used a scrollviewer and hide the scrollbars.  This seems like a heavy solution, but will work for the time being.  I definately will need to find something lighter weight when I move this to Windows Phone 7.

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Margin="0,0,158,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="123" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid x:Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="169" MaxHeight="145" Height="141" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Button Content="Button" Margin="25,42,0,60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="71"/>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="76" Margin="25,0,0,-83" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="81"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIElement.ClipToBounds`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True">

    ...

</Grid>
```

Comment: No, it works on Grid too.  Give it a try with Coach David's Xaml above.

Comment: No property with the name of ClipToBounds exist.  There is a Clip.

Comment: It does exist for all UIElement derived objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Its not in Silverlight just WPF.  Is there another way to do this.  I am not married to using a grid.  I just want to create the effect of the parent container growing and displaying additional child controls.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you seem to be asking is how the `Grid` control works by default, e.g.:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <DockPanel Margin="50" Background="Azure" > 
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock>The only part of this control that gets rendered is that which is inside the bounds of the Grid.</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

I can only assume that you're asking something else.  But what?

Comment: I think your right but this only seem to apply to the root layout.